# How to stream audio for only a known duration using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer, itunes-store

I'm using AVPlayer (I don't need to, but I wanna stream it and start playing as soon as possible) to play an m4a file (it's an iTunes audio preview). Only I only want it to play a part of that file.
I'm able to set a start time but not an end time.

Using a timer is not working because I'm using URL as a http address. I'm playing as it loads, without downloading the file.

I also saw solutions in Objective-C to use KVO to know when music starts playing but I'm thinking this is not the best approach since I'm using swift and also because of glitches that may occur so the song will not stop at the right moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a  [addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1388027-addboundarytimeobserver) to your AVPlayer as follow:

update: **Xcode 8.3.2 • Swift 3.1**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var player: AVPlayer!
    var observer: Any!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/audio.mp3") else { return }
        player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let boundary: TimeInterval = 30
        let times = [NSValue(time: CMTimeMake(Int64(boundary), 1))]
        observer = player.addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: times, queue: nil) {
            [weak self] time in
            print("30s reached")
            if let observer = self?.observer {
                self?.player.removeTimeObserver(observer)
            }
            self?.player.pause()
        }
        player.play()
        print("started loading")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! it works perfectly with the time hardcoded. But I tried     audioPlayer.addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes([CMTimeMake(Int64(timeInterval), 1)], queue: dispatch_get_main_queue()) { but it doesn't work. Do you know what type should be passed as a parameter?

Comment: [AnyObject] An array of NSValue objects containing CMTime values representing the times at which to invoke block.

Comment: no there was no typo actually. I'm adding an array of CMTime but I'm getting Cannot invoke 'addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes' with an argument list of type '([CMTime], queue: dispatch_queue_t!, () -> Void)'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87322/discussion-between-lucas-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: You need to convert CMTime to NSValue

Comment: Can you explain the logic of what you're doing? What is time and observer?

Comment: This is just to add a time limit to the audio. If adds an observer for the times in the array. Every time the audio reaches one of the times that method gets called. In the example above it will happen only once