# AVQueuePlayer perform action when currentTime is 'n' seconds from duration

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerlayer, cmtime

I need to add a `CABasicAnimation` to an `AVPlayerLayer` when an `AVQueuePlayer`'s `playerItem` is one second from finishing (playerItem's duration - 1). It's a basic crossfade. I just can't seem to figure out how to tell when I've arrived at the right time. Using the code below, I've added a periodic time observer. Is there any way to know when my playerItem is one second from ending?

```
timeObserverToken = player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [unowned self] time in

    let fadeOutTime = CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: time.timescale)
    let duration = self.currentItem()?.duration
    let convertedDuration = CMTimeConvertScale(duration!, time.timescale, .default)

    if CMTimeCompare(time, CMTimeSubtract(convertedDuration, fadeOutTime)) == 0 {
        self.playerLayer.add(self.fadeOut, forKey: "fadeOut")
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the BoundaryTimeObserver  https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1388027-addboundarytimeobserver

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32082530/2303865

Comment: That definitely helps! I have one video clip, taken from an iPhone, that, even with the BoundaryTimeObserver, it fades and then for a split second then reappears before the queuePlayer plays the next playerItem (when using the second commented `time` variable below). Using uncommented `time` variable it's better, but it stutters a little. Do I need to trim the clip?
    
`let timeInterval: TimeInterval = seconds - 1.0`
`//  let time = NSValue(time: CMTimeMake(Int64(timeInterval), 1))`
`let time = NSValue(time: CMTimeSubtract(item.duration, CMTimeMake(1, timeScale())))`